# Adding the Admin Bar to a page with a custom template

Tags: page-template, admin-bar

I created a stripped-down page template to use for my landing pages. But I must have cut too much out of it, because I've lost the WordPress 3.1+ Admin Bar.

What functions do I need to call to get the Admin Bar to appear at the top of the page again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure exactly, but adding the following two functions should get it to work and save you other headaches as well:

Right before the closing head tag add:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

And right before the closing body tag add:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: That did the trick. You need both wp_head() and wp_footer() in order to get the Admin Bar to appear. Thanks!

Comment: Right on, good to know. Instinct told me you needed both, but I wasn't certain :)

Comment: this is great .. thats worked for me but styles distroyed all my menus disappered after those two changes